# Protractor+Appium for Mobile web on iOS

Tags: ios, protractor, alert, appium

I'm trying `Appium+Protractor` to test angular web application on iOS device.

When I'm running the script only URL is hitting on the device but script is not executing. `Appium` is keep on showing below lines

> atom did not return yet, checking to see if we are blocked by an alert
>   info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: "au.alertIsPresent()"
>   info: [debug] Sending command to instruments: au.alertIsPresent()

there is no alert in application.

Couldn't find any solution on web. Any solution for it???